# Is there an equivalent of the /// <see cref="member"/> comment in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on a new coding standard for my company.  One of the recommendations is to add standard comments to clarify binding data sources.

Is there an equivalent to the `/// <see cref="filename.cs"/>` comment for XAML files?

Comment: No. There are comments and regions but no xml documentation comments.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

I am afraid you'll have to use "manual" text-only references inside ordinary `<!-- -->` tags.

UWP and [WinUI](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/) supports [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) using the `x:Bind` markup.